# Really custom urls for backbone models http verbs

Tags: rest, url, backbone.js

I have the following resource:

```
PUT /fruit/{fruitId}/in/{basketId}
```

And I want to know what is the best way to build up this kind of url in backbone in my models/collections. What I don't want is to concatenate Strings like this:

```
"/fruit/" + fid + "/in/" + bid; //Bad, MUST be something better in life!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [sprintf](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js). This would allow you to do something like:

```
sprintf('/fruit/%d/in/%d', fid, bid)
```

Sprintf offers more than just concatenation. The %d placeholder will format an integer as a decimal. There's other formats if you need them.

There's also an associated [NPM module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/sprintf-js).